# Java - How to create a property key given any string

Tags: java, properties

I'ven looking around and so far it seems like the only constrain for a property key is to avoid spaces (in between) and = (obviously) for the key, i.e. a.property.key = value

I was wondering if there are other restrictions (or java build-in method), because I would like to take any given string and be able to normalized so it works like a property key, for example:

Given String: `This & this _5  will be used as a prop-key`

Property key: `this&this_5.will.be.used.as.a.prop.key`

Comment: But........why?

Comment: Lets say we have many sites that need a different slogan, we could use the site name to create a key that will be used to get the slogan from the properties. So the site name is My Site, then the slogan key will be slogan.my.site=Hello!

Comment: Do you mean the domain by site name or something else? In any case, that would be a very poor approach. If you're thinking of property files as a good place to store all kinds of general data, they're not. You should probably consider using database for that sort of information, and keep property files at a minimum.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear about the context of my example, these are sites within the same portal, so admin users can create "sites" and give them different displaying names (to be displayed within the page header)

Comment: Yeah, definitely database stuff then. Don't even think about abusing property files for those.

Comment: should not matter that much to the point of the question which is mainly the  the restrictions for creating a prop key given any string

Comment: that's an example any way, ideally it could be implemented so admin users could set the slogan related to the site and just save it to db, but again, that's not the point, I appreciate the advice and I agree on not abusing properties though

Comment: No, but it does affect my interest in a question. If you really want to know, you can check the source. Of course `java.util.Properties` might not be used everywhere (it's not that great), so behaviour may vary between frameworks.

Comment: The range of the implementation approaches I have is limited by many project related factors (time, and significance of the task) which are not very important here a the moment and the reason why I tried to be concrete about the question,I hope you didn't lost interest if you had insights about property keys restrictions, I'm was not trying to sound rude at all :)

Comment: cool thank you Kayaman

Comment: Note also that if you use the site name in the property key, you assume the site name never changes. If it does, then you'll have to change all the keys which becomes unnecessarily brittle compared to what you'd have with database storage. There's also a potential security risk.

Comment: you are right, the site names are almost set in stone atm, anyway I'll bring this up and check if we can go with the better way, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no constraints, just use escaped characters:

```
This\ &\ this\=\ _5=prop value
```

then in java:

```
properties.getProperty("This & this= _5");// retrurs "prop value"
```

Comment: : = / and #(at the beginning), space, unicode chars like \u0009 and special chars like \n\r.

Comment: I don't enough rep to vote up, so here is a simple "thank you!"